# Should I use "maxrows" in my query? ColdFusion / SQL

Tags: database, coldfusion, cfquery

Is it necessary to use maxrows="1" when searching for a row with a numeric primary key?

```
<cfquery maxrows="1">  
   select *
   from table
   where RowID = #NumericVariable#
</cfquery>
```

Does ColdFusion have some kind of SQL binding or anything else that makes it better / faster / superior if maxrows is included or excluded?

Comment: If the table is structured properly (ie the field you're limiting on is the primary key), then limiting by one is redundant.

Comment: @Mark I think you can post that as the answer :)

Comment: I did get the answer I was looking for. I just want to clarify that including maxrows is NOT redundant when you specify in SQL that you are looking for a single row. When using where RowID = #NumericVariable#, you are REQUESTING a single row. Using CF's maxrows limits the output of the data that you requested.  So, you could ask for 50 rows using SQL and then limit the output to a single row. That's not the same as requesting a single row and outputting the single row.

Comment: The topic is clearly discussed here: http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2009/8/12/MAXROWS-Attribute--Not-as-good-as-I-thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**maxrows** limits the number of results in the query variable *after* its returned from the database.

If you are only ever returning a single result then this is not going to have any impact at all on the performance of your query.

ColdFusion does allow you to pass bind parameters using the CFQUERYPARAM tag.

For example:

```
<cfquery name="q">
    SELECT property1, property2, property3 
    FROM yourTable 
    WHERE RowID = <cfqueryparam value="#NumericVariable#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" />
</cfquery>
```

You can hope to improve the speed on your database by providing a bind parameter and specifying the properties to return. This may allow for better query caching and performance improvements depending on the database engine you are using.

I'd add its generally more secure to use CFQUERYPARAM than to leave variables unqualified and potentially open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: This was EXACTLY the answer I was looking for: "maxrows limits the number of results in the query variable after its returned from the database." If this is true, then it's completely unnecessary to include "maxrows".

Comment: The topic is clearly discussed here: http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2009/8/12/MAXROWS-Attribute--Not-as-good-as-I-thought

Answer (score 4):

### No.

If the table is structured properly (i.e. the field you're limiting on is the primary key), then limiting by one is redundant. By definition, a primary key uniquely identifies one row.

Comment: I agree it's redundant.  Does ColdFusion have some kind of SQL binding or anything else that makes it better / faster if maxrows is included or excluded?

Comment: Always limit records on the database side *not* with CF. It is a waste of resources to have the database return information that CF is just going to discard anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would **test it** out:

Run your above code as it is for 10 different values of RowID, and compare it with running the code with a maxrows condition as well. If you see the execution times are always better for the latter, you have your definitive answer!

Answer (score 0):

How that works, is that cfquery still tries to query all the table row's that fit your where clauses, but it only returns x results.

So not exactly great for performance.

Another alternative at least in SQL Server, is the SET ROWCOUNT # command, which actually limits the number of records it returns. However this can affect all cfqueries if you have check persistant in cfadmin.

Or in mysql there is the limit command.

I wish there was a better solution, but there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not unnecessary at all. While maxrows with a real database query may be questionnable and replaced with a SQL limit clause (mySQL), that optimizes performance of the db as well, with "query of queries", the maxrow-parameter is the only possibility to limit the resultset, since query of queries does not support limit clause.
e.g.:

```
<!--- get the newest file date from an existing query --->
<cfquery name="oldest" dbtype="query" maxrows="1">
SELECT dateLastModified FROM dirQuery ORDER BY dateLastModified DESC 
</cfquery>
```

Just wanted to point out this context.